GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.mediaStatus is always nil
In my iOS app I am casting videos to Chromecast and I also need to know current stream position. I already tried this solution. However, GCKCastContext.sharedInstance().sessionManager.currentSession?.remoteMediaClient?.mediaStatus is always nil. Do you know if some specific steps are required to initialise remoteMediaClient?
